# how do I reference a workbook not using the workbook's name?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I need to write a macro in one workbook, but in that marco I need to tell it to go to another workbook to copy some data and paste in the workbook that has the macro in, now I have a problem of referencing the other workbook because the name of that workbook will always be different, but the sheet I am copying from will always has the same name. Is there a simply way to ask Macro to always grab the data from the correct openbook without using the name of the workbook?

Many thanks

Comment: If you don't know what it is called, don't know what its ordinal in the collection is, never set a workbook object variable when you opened it and cannot identify it by looping through all workbooks looking for a unique property then no, you will never reliably know where the second workbook is.

Comment: Are you saying that the workbook you need to reference without using a name is the one that contains the macro? If so, you can use `Thisworkbook`

Comment: you could ask them to select/activate the open workbook, but of course that's leaving room for more user-error, which you'd have to trap and validate the structure of the workbook is consistent with your procedure's expectations, etc.... The better way to do this is to have the macro *open* the workbook for you, you can use the `FileDialog` to allow the user to select the workbook.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the ***only*** other workbook open, then you can use something like and will be fairly reliable:

```
Function GetOtherWorkbook(sheetName$)
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each wb in Workbooks
    If Not wb = ThisWorkbook Then
        For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = sheetName Then
                Set GetOtherWorkbook = wb
                GoTo EarlyExit
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
MsgBox sheetName & " not found in any open workbook.", vbCritical
Set GetOtherWorkbook = Nothing
EarlyExit:
Exit Function
```

Then use this function to return `otherWB` as the variable for the other workbook:

```
Set otherWB = GetOtherWorkbook("some sheet name")

If otherWB Is Nothing Then 
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Do stuff...
End If
```

Otherwise no, you cannot *reliably* reference another workbook without knowing the name or it's index in the `Workbooks` collection.

**NOTE** If there are other open workbooks, then this method may return false positive if multiple workbooks contain the same sheet name.